# Can't connect to database with 000webhost

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm trying to learn php but when I attempt to connect to a mysql database, I get this error. I don't think anything is wrong with the code itself but perhaps there is an error on the hosts side? I'm using 000webhost so.

> Warning: mysqli::mysqli() [mysqli.mysqli]: (28000/1045): Access denied
>   for user 'a7976620_db1user'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in
>   /home/a7976620/public_html/index.php on line 17

Here is my php:

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "a7976620_db1user";
$password = "******";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
echo "Connected successfully";
?>
```

Comment: check your username and password.

Comment: I removed the password if you're talking about the ******

Comment: clearly saying that permission issue

Comment: I'm saying check your actual username and actual password for db. Because the warning you are getting states that : " Access denied for user 'a7976620_db1user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)"

Comment: I don't have experience with mysql. What do you suggest I do? Obviously add the permissions but can you tell me how?

Comment: Just checked the username and password, everything is fine. So the issue is something else.

Comment: Can you specify the DB name also as the fourth parameter

Comment: $servername = "localhost";
$username = "a7976620_db1user";
$password = "******";
$databasename = "a7976620_db1"; I tried that just now. Not working either.

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $databasename);

Just tried that but sadly, that's not working.

Comment: contact host customer service after scrutinizing cpanel or whatever they have for you

Comment: http://www.000webhost.com/faq.php?ID=25

Comment: Thanks drew. Sadly, I now have a new problem which is basically the same. Warning: mysqli::mysqli() [mysqli.mysqli]: (HY000/1130): Host '31.170.160.103' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server in /home/a7976620/public_html/index.php on line 18

Comment: Don't give up on me brother!

Comment: you have to allow an incoming request on your DB server on port 3306 for your IP address "31.170.160.103" to have a connection.

Comment: How should I go about doing that exactly?

Comment: If your mysql database is not on the same server(localhost) you need to give it access from a remote server for that mysql user/database for your server. See this article for some steps that might help you. It sounds like it might be remote.

http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/mysql-connect-to-your-database-remotely

Comment: @Sokaz Did you managed to solve your problem? I think the $servername should be something like "mysql13.000webhost.com" without the double qutoes

Answer (score -1):

In https://www.000webhost.com, there are two options in the cPanel:

1. Fix ownership and
2. Fix file permissions

You can apply this and it will be fine.