# cannot connect to databasee in 000webhost

Tags: php, mysql

Here is my connection code, I have made mysql database in 000webhost and I have also uploaded file in 000webhost but every time I am getting error like this "
PHP Error Message

> Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Access denied for
>   user 'a1346052'@'10.1.1.39' (using password: YES) in
>   /home/a1346052/public_html/connection.php on line 7

Free Web Hosting
Could not connect database
please help me on this, Thanks

```
<?php

$mysql_hostname = "mysql13.000webhost.com";

$mysql_user = "a1346052";

$mysql_password = "*****";

$mysql_database = "a1346052_simple";

$prefix = "";

   $bd = mysql_connect($mysql_hostname, $mysql_user, $mysql_password) or die("Could not connect database");    
        mysql_select_db($mysql_database, $bd) or die("Could not select database");
?
```

Comment: Why you are still using `mysql_connect()` , It is deprecated, so please start usig mysqli or PDO ?

Comment: And please remove password from your post.

Comment: Well, it's either a wrong username, a wrong password or you are connecting from a host that is not allowed. The error message is pretty self explaining.

Comment: From the comments of  [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33295846/cant-connect-to-database-with-000webhost?rq=1): https://www.000webhost.com/faq.php?ID=25

Comment: thanks a lot will look onto this :)

Comment: As edited posts will still show your password, you should change it immediately.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think your username will only be that. There will certainly be a username along with the random number. Ex: **a7238414_username**. Try running following code and see what result it gives.

```
$dbhost = 'mysql13.000webhost.com';
   $dbuser = 'a7238414_username';
   $dbpass = '***';
   $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
   if(! $conn )
   {
     die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
   }
   echo 'Connected successfully';
   mysql_close($conn);
```

Just a headsup, mysql is deprecated. You should start using mysqli or PDO :)